# AppCenter does not start

Tags: appcenter, release-odin

I installed elementary OS 6, done a few things on it including installing Firefox from FlatHub. Then I restarted the PC and tried to launch the AppCenter again. However, this didn't do anything. Trying to run it from the Terminal, I get:

```
$ io.elementary.appcenter
Failed to register: Timeout was reached
```

Nonetheless, running `--help` does finish:

```
$ io.elementary.appcenter --help

Usage:
  io.elementary.appcenter [OPTION?]

Help Options:
  -h, --help                              Show help options
  --help-all                              Show all help options
  --help-gapplication                     Show GApplication options
  --help-gtk                              Show GTK+ Options

Application Options:
  -u, --show-updates                      Display the Installed Panel
  -s, --silent                            Run the Application in background
  -l, --load-local=FILENAME               Add a local AppStream XML file to the package list
  -f, --fake-package-update=PACKAGES?     Add the package name to update results so that it is shown as an update
  --display=DISPLAY                       X display to use
```

Comment: A reboot fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

use `sudo io.elementary.appcenter`

Comment: That sounds like a fairly terrible idea. You should never randomly throw `sudo` at GUI applications when they don't work.